# Give class to list item if item has submenu in custom menu structure

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I'm making a custom structure for my main menu in my first Wordpress theme. This is my code so far:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
    $link = $item->url;
    $title = $item->title;

    // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
    if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):

    // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
    $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li>
       <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
    <?php echo $title; ?>
       </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>
    <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <?php endif; ?>

    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" ><?php echo $title; ?></i></a>
    </li>

    <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>

    </ul>

    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>

    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>
    <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Currently it generates the menu I want, except for a specific class I want my submenu parents to have.

Foreach list item that includes a submenu, I want it to have the class "hasSubmenu". How do I make this work?

Comment: Also... if you add the php tag to your question it'll be answered a lot quicker. Could also do this using jQuery if you'd like me to give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the same code that you used to add the submenu to add the class to the submenu parent? This is the code that's doing that:

```
<?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">

<?php endif; ?>
```

So add something like this to your li item...

```
<li class="
    <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>

    <?php echo "hasSubmenu"; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
">
```

Hope that helps!